# Can't access internal URLs of website directly

Tags: python, http, http-headers, httpsession

I see there are some URLs fetching metadata(json) for browser to render website i.e. when I hit example.com, in `Firefox's developers view`-> `Network tab`; some URL like `https://example.com/server/getdata?cmd=showResults`.

So, my question is I can access the that URL in new tab in same firefox window(expected json data). But I can't access the same URL in other firefox window(retuning empty json). It is maintaining some kind of session(may be with cookies?). I copied exact same http headers values from developers view and created python script with `request` at that moment to test. But the python script is retuning empty json

### Example Screenshot

[image: Request URL]

### Python Code

```
parameter = {
    "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Cache-Control": "no-store, max-age=0",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Length": "13175",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "DNT": "1",
    "Host": "in.example.com",
    "Cookie": '__cfduid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx; __cfruid=xxxxxxx-1520022406; mqttuid=1.361660689',
    "Referer": "https://in.example.com/page1/page2",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}
response = requests.post(url="https://in.example.com/serv/getData?cmd=XXXX&type=XX&XXXX=1&_=1520022652009", data=parameter)
#print(dir(response))
print(response.headers)
print(response.json())
```

How can I simulate the session and directly hit the URL without hiting the root website?

PS: The site is static website

### UPDATE1

changed `header=parameters`

```
response = requests.get(url="https://in.example.com/server1/getallData?cmd=xxxx&_=1520097652234", headers=parameter)

requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='in.example.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /server1/getallData?cmd=xxxxx&_=1520097652934 (Caused by <class 'ConnectionResetError'>: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer)
```

Getting `Connection Reset` exception. Looks like CF is doing something? any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the "headers" as `data`?

You should use `headers` instead.

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Bot'}
requests.get('example.com/params', headers=headers)
```

Comment: Can you check the Update1 in my question. getting connection reset exception